# Reply to an Outlook email using the MessageID and Win32com module in Python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

So I know how to look through the inbox (or any other folder) and find emails to reply to. However in my case, I have a .msg email file from which I extract the MessageID, and I'm looking to use win32com module to reply to that specific email.

Basically I'm looking for something like this:

```
from extract_msg import Message
msg = Message("message.msg")
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0x0)

mail.To = "; ".join(to)
mail.Subject = subject
mail.Body = body
mail.InReplyTo = msg.messageId
```

I understand that something similar is doable using the smtplib module using:

```
message['In-Reply-To'] = msg.messageId
```

but I cannot get smtplb to work with Outlook. And thus, I'm using win32com.

Comment: Where did you get a source message `msg = Message("message.msg")`? Is the PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID property set on the message?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev That's what I found elsewhere to parse .msg files. It works fine, but I'm not sure if the msg.messageId attribute is the same as the PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID you're referring to.

Comment: I'd recommend extracting the value from any Outlook message and run your code with that value. Do you get the expected results in Outlook in that case?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev what's a better way to extract the message id value from a .msg file then? I'm currently using this and setting the PR_IN_REPLY_TO_ID to it but it doesn't work as intended. The received email does not show the email chain/history.

Comment: Have you tried to use any mail item from Outlook?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I just tried using "outlook.OpenSharedItem("test_msg.msg")" and accessed the PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID property, and it seems it's the same thing as the messageId from "msg = Message("message.msg").messageId". However it still doesn't show in the received email that it's in response to another email. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do you expect the item to be displayed in the same conversation list?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what it's called but I expect something like this: https://ibb.co/3Rp05jx

Comment: Your question is about setting the `In-Reply-To` property/header on the email, right?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev more accurately I want the received email to remain in the email thread /history of the original email. As in, when the receiver gets the email, it shows that it's in reply to the original email like in the screenshot above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PR_IN_REPLY_TO_ID` property should be set to the `PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID` property value. Make sure that such value exists in Outlook messages. You can get the value in Outlook in the following way (the sample is in C# but the Outlook object model is common for all kind of programming languages):

```
string PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PropertyAccessor pal = mailItem.PropertyAccessor;
string Internet_Message_Id = pal.GetProperty(PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID).ToString();
```

Comment: so i've done just that, however in the received email it does not show the email history/thread, it doesn't show the email that was replied to. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or what, but I'd like the email history to show on the receiving end if possible.

Comment: It would be great to see how it is displayed and what exactly you expect to get in Outlook.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what it's called but I expect something like this: ibb.co/3Rp05jx , more accurately I want the received email to remain in the email thread /history of the original email. As in, when the receiver gets the email, it shows that it's in reply to the original email like in the screenshot above.

Comment: I'd suggest posting a separate question because from your post the end goal was not clear. The goal was to set the `PR_IN_REPLY_TO_ID` property correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71910215/reply-to-an-outlook-email-in-the-same-email-history-conversation-using-the-messa
Done.

Comment: It makes sense to close this one by marking the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `PR_IN_REPLY_TO_ID` MAPI property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1042001F"`) using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`.

Comment: From what I was able to understand from this reply and the documentation, I used the code:
"mail.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(["http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1042001F"], [msg.messageId])"
But I receive an error saying "The parameter is incorrect."

Comment: Why are you using []?

Comment: I used the brackets because the documentation used arrays. I removed the brackets and tried it again, the email went through with no errors, but it was not in response to the other email. As in, on outlook, the received email does not show the email history/thread. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Do you see that property on the message in the Sent Items folder in OutlookSpy (I am its author - https://www.dimastr.com/outspy)? -  click IMessage button.

Comment: I did, and confirmed the message ID is correct and I'm setting the PR_IN_REPLY_TO_ID to it. However it still does not show in the same email history/conversation. I basically want it to show like this: https://ibb.co/3Rp05jx

Comment: If you look at the sent message source in Gmail, does it have the right header?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243975/discussion-between-put-me-and-dmitry-streblechenko).

Comment: Let's continue the conversation here - let everybody benefit from the discussion

Comment: Alright, I'm not sure I understand. What's the right header and how do I look at it in Gmail?

Comment: Your goal was to set the right In-Reply-To, correct? Was it set to the value in your code?

Comment: When I prompt it in the code using GetProperty, yes it was set correctly. But when I use outspy and inspect the properties of the sent email, I don't see a PR_IN_REPLY_TO_ID property at all.

Comment: When and how do you set the property? Do you call MailItem.Save?